# AngularJS Factory Not Working?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

So I'm following along with the [thinkster.io MEAN stack tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) and I have completed everything up until "Beginning Node" but my application is not working as expected.

When viewing a post's comments, it seems like the factory is not properly sharing its variable. The title (and link, if present in that post record) is not displayed, nor are comments (if that post record has associated comments).

I've looked through my code several times and made sure it follows the tutorial, but I cannot get it to work! What am I doing wrong?

**indexV2.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js">         </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="appV3.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
  </head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <!-- where ui-router places templates, depending on the state -->
        <ui-view></ui-view>

       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <!-- begin home.html inline template -->
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPostV2()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Post</button>
    </form>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
      <a href="{{post.link}}" ng-show="post.link">{{post.title}}</a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">{{post.title}}</span>
      - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
      - <span>
        <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
      <!-- begin posts.html inline template -->
      <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
        </h3>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
          {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          {{comment.body}}
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addComment()" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new comment</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**appV3.js**

```
// instantiate app, call it flapperNews, and declare the ui.router dependency
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

// Set up states using the config function
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', { // homepage state
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',  // specify template (will be inline, in index.html, for this example)
                controller: 'MainCtrl'  // assign a controller
            })
            .state('posts', { // state that will display comments associated with a post
                url: '/posts/{id}', // id is a route parameter, made available to our controller
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home'); // redirect unspecified routes
    }
]);

// factory that will share the posts array with controllers
app.factory('posts', [function () {
    var o = {   // create object that will hold our posts array
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

// controller for "home" state
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',    // inject service into controller (by adding it as a parameter)
    function($scope, posts) {

        // bind (not just assign) the service variable to our scope
            // any changes in either will be reflected in the other
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;

        $scope.posts = [    // array of objects
            {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 3, url: ''}, // object (collection of properties) with 2 properties
            {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 4, url: ''},
            {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 1, url: ''},
            {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 2, url: ''},
            {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 6, url: ''}
        ];

        $scope.addPostV2 = function() {
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {  // if empty or not set
                return;                                 // exit function
            }
            $scope.posts.push({ // push new object into array
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
                upvotes: 0,
                comments: [ // fake array
                    {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                    {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
                ]
            });
            $scope.title = '';  // empty the property (the model in the form)
            $scope.link = '';
        }

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {  // pass the instance of post (passed in calling function, by reference - located in HTML)
            post.upvotes  += 1;
        }

    }
]);

// new controller for "posts" state
app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {

        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id]; // Grab a post from posts, using the id parameter from $stateParams (in URL)

        $scope.addComment = function() {
            if($scope.body === '') {
                return;
            }
            $scope.post.comments.push({
                body: $scope.body,
                author: 'user',
                upvotes: 0
            });
            $scope.body = '';
        }

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(comment) {
            comment.upvotes += 1;
        }
    }
]);
```

Thank you for your help ahead of time

Comment: I apologize @Sajeetharan, I just added some more details to my question in the second paragraph. Esentially, while the home.html template can properly reference the posts object and display its properties in the template, the posts.html template cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine your code:

```
$scope.posts = posts.posts;
```

After this line of code, here's what you have:

```
posts.posts -------> []
                     ^
$scope.posts --------|
```

So both $scope.posts and posts.posts are referencing the same, empty array.

Now the following line:

```
$scope.posts = [    // array of objects
    {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 3, url: ''},
    ...
];
```

This line doesn't populate the array that is referenced by the service and by the scope. It assigns a new array to $scope.posts. So you end up with

```
posts.posts -------> []

$scope.posts ------> [{title: 'post 1', upvotes: 3, url: ''}, ...]
```

So, when you go to the next screen, and get back an element from posts.posts:

```
$scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
```

you get back nothing, since posts.posts is still the original empty array.

Instead of

```
$scope.posts = [    // array of objects
    {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 3, url: ''},
    ...
];
```

You need

```
$scope.posts.push({title: 'post 1', upvotes: 3, url: ''});
...
```

Then you will fill the array that is referenced by the controller and by the service.

Note that making the detail page depend on the list page like that is a bad, bad idea anyway: if the user refreshes the details page, the application will start from scratch, and the details page won't find anything in the array. You should get the post by sending a GET request to the server, to get the post.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  I was mistaken when I thought `$scope.posts = [ 
    {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 3, url: ''},
    ...
];` would add the objects to the existing array (held in the factory) rather than point to a new, empty array - which is actually what it did. Thanks for this clarification - I greatly appreciate it!